# Motherboard is stuck at DRAM LED

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I am getting super strange issue... My pc is Ryzen 9 5900x with 8GB x 4 = DDR4 3200 RAM. It was working perfectly from months but suddenly from 2-3 days it started getting hang. Today when I booted my machine it works for first 10-15 mins and then suddenly crashed after that motherboard stuck at DRAM LED.
I removed all the RAM and only connected 1 RAM on 2nd slot and my PC start booted successfully. What should I do now? My system is just running on 1 8Gig RAM.

PC Specs::

```
CPU=> Ryzen 9 5900x
Motherboard => Asus ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING (WI-FI)
RAM => G-Skill 4 x 8 GB DDR4 3200
```

Comment: Your PSU dying?

Comment: I guess no... I do tons of work on this machine GPU and CPU both get 100% while rendering and compiling stuff but I never get PSU fail issue

Comment: @GerardH.Pille just now I switched my PSU and still its same

Comment: Done some overclocking? Dying after 15' makes me think of capacitors or something temperature related. If you haven't touched the hardware before the problem started, MB may have developed a fault.